# Can't identify this bolt. Please help. Bolt from adjustable stem

Tags: maintenance, bolt

I found this bolt from my friends bike (from an adjustable stem).

And I need another bolt like this for my second hand bike because it didn't come with it. It would be much appreciated if you can help me with this. Thank you.

The black part on the top is just grease.

[image]

Comment: We need dimensions. The diameter of the thread and the thread pitch to start with (probably in mm)

Comment: Take it to a good hardware store and ask for one. They will sell you a box of 50 for $/£/€ 10. I suspect it is one from the DIN 912 norm - dimensions are here: http://www.schrauben-lexikon.de/norm/DIN_912.asp

Comment: It's a bolt.  With a diameter, length, and thread that can be measured.  And no doubt a "head" with an allen recess.

Comment: @ChristianLindig politely, avoid hardware store bolts.  They tend to be okay for low load situations, but you generally want hardened bolts for high load areas on a bike.  So hardware store bolts are totally fine for attaching a fender/mudguard, probably okay for a rack, but definitely not for a child's seat or a stem or a saddle clamp.

Comment: @Funkollector I'd recommend you take the good bolt along to a LBS and ask for some help.  A decent LBS will simply pull one from their parts bin and give it to you for free or for very little cost.   Another option is to look around for a bike-cooperative in your city and see what they can do to help you.  The part may be free or they may expect a reasonable donation.

Comment: @Funkollector the bolt should probably have threadlock on the threads, not grease.  I might use grease around the outside of the bolt head as a water-excluder, but low-strength threadlocker on the threads would be safer, especially when its torqued to spec.

Comment: @Christian the head diameter is too small in relation to the thread diameter to be a standard socket cap head. While I'm more willing than Criggie to use generic hardware (having ridden a few BSOs with obviously rubbish fasteners) I still wouldn't use one where a single point failure would be catastrophic.

Comment: @ChrisH The norm (DIN 912/ISO ISO 4762) specifies a maximum diameter for the head - so screws can vary in head diameter within a given size. Furthermore, maximum head diameter to thread diameter is not constant across sizes but decreases towards larger sizes. Anyway -- some more details from the original author would go a long way.

Comment: @Christian the vast majority sold for general use are just under the standard maximum. And that ratio is much too small for anything I'm used to - up to about M12

Comment: I don't think this is particularly bike-related. A google search about determining thread size should be all you need.

Comment: Allen-head bolts are usually described as a capscrew, rather than a bolt. We need to see the head - it may well carry markings that indicate the material type / strength rating.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like any standard M5 or M6 bolt. Go to a hardware store, find a nut that will screw on, and find a new bolt with that nut.

Comment: Are you advising that it's safe to use a generic hardware store bolt?

Comment: @DavidRicherby they are typically made of hardened steel so yes.